# How to Deserialize XMLElement with same name

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization

I have XML root element and XML Element with same name, I am not sure how I should change my model class

The following code works as far as XML Element is not repeated with same name, in my case Gender list=1

Changing XML out format is not possible as it is coming from another system, unless filter out in C# code level

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <Gender>
   <Gender list="1">
    <Item>
      <CODE>M</CODE>
      <DESCRIPTION>Male</DESCRIPTION> 
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <CODE>F</CODE>
      <DESCRIPTION>Female</DESCRIPTION>
    </Item>
   </Gender>
  </Gender>
```

### Model Class

```
 public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}


public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

### XML Parsing Class

```
public static class XMLPrasing
{
    public static Object ObjectToXML(string xml, Type objectType)
    {
        StringReader strReader = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = null;
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
        Object obj = null;
        try
        {
            strReader = new StringReader(xml);
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
            xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            //Handle Exception Code
            var s = "d";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlReader != null)
            {
                xmlReader.Close();
            }
            if (strReader != null)
            {
                strReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

### SECOND UPDATE

If I change my code with different Gender name as following then this work, question remain same how to handle with same name

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Gender>
 <GenderX list="1">
   <Item>
    <CODE>M</CODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>Male</DESCRIPTION>
   </Item>
   <Item>
    <CODE>F</CODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>Female</DESCRIPTION>
   </Item>
  </GenderX>
 </Gender>
```

### Model class

```
  [XmlRoot("Gender")]
public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("GenderX")]
    public List<GenderX> GenderXList = new List<GenderX>();       
}


public class GenderX
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}



public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer

```
[XmlRoot("Gender")]
public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("Gender")]
    public List<GenderListWrap> _GenderListWrap = new List<GenderListWrap>();       
}


public class GenderListWrap
{
    [XmlAttribute("list")]
    public string _ListTag { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> _GenderList = new List<Item>();
}



public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one top level Gender element, then this is enough:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Gender")]
public class Genders
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender")]
    public Gender gender { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}


public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Generic method for deserialize XMLString.
This method take xml string and deserialized sender model Type.

You must use Model deserialized xml to property like this , and You should not forget to write `[Serializable]` for class attribute and `[XmlElement]` for property attribute

```
  [Serializable]
  public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}


public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

 public static T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            Log.Debug("Deserialize" + typeof(T).Name, "xml string Deserialize ediliyor" + Environment.NewLine + input);            

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "SetDefaultNamespace"); // optinal parameters DefaultNamespace
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                var desearializedObject = (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
                Log.Debug("Deserialize" + typeof(T).Name, "Obje Deserialize işlemi tamamlandı");
                return desearializedObject;
            }
        }


    Deserialize<Gender>(xmlString);
```